# how to display product images using angular?

Tags: angular, carousel

in `component show` I have a `product`, a `product` has an `images field`, which contains an array of `images links`, and in my `component show` there is a `carousel`, so I want to display these `images` in `carousel`, and I don't know how.

**show.component.html**

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active" *ngFor="let product.images of image">
                                <img src="{{ annonce.image }}" class="d-block w-100" style="width:600px;height:400px" alt="image">
                            </div>
                            
                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                            data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                            data-bs-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

**the product images field**

```
images: "http://localhost/aswakb/public/storage/[\"annonces\\\\September2020\\\\animaux1.jpg\",\"annonces\\\\September2020\\\\animaux2.jpg\",\"annonces\\\\September2020\\\\animaux3.jpg\",\"annonces\\\\September2020\\\\animaux4.jpg\",\"annonces\\\\September2020\\\\animaux5.jpg\"]"
```

Comment: You could use a library like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples) or [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/carousel?tab=overview) or [my library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap), or just copy [the following code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/carousel) into your project

Comment: @Pieterjan i copy the following code into my project but give me error :` bs-carousel is not a known element` ,

Comment: You have to import the `BsCarouselModule` into the module declaring your component

Comment: You can check this project that I created without any libraries https://github.com/jaws97/customswiper